# Update user password with LDAP when the user has the flag 'User must change password at next logon' set, leads to error 49, subcode 773

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

When I try to change the password of a user via LDAP, in whose AD account the setting is set that the password must be changed at the next login, I get the following error:

`cause: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v3839`

Subcode 773 indicates that the user must reset the password, which is exactly what I intend to do right now.

With the following code I can successfully change the password if the above flag is **not** set:

```
 public void updateUserPassword(String user, String oldPassword,
                                   String newPassword) throws NamingException, LoginException {
        try {
            InitialDirContext ctx = this.getContext();

            String filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";
            String baseDn = (String) this.getActiveDirectoryProps().get("baseDN_User");

            // Search for user entry
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            ctls.setReturningObjFlag(true);

            String[] returnAttrs = new String[3];
            returnAttrs[0] = "cn"; // Common Name
            returnAttrs[1] = "displayName"; 
            returnAttrs[2] = "description";

            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> enumSearchResult = ctx.search(baseDn, filter, returnAttrs, ctls);


            if (enumSearchResult.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = enumSearchResult.next();
        
                DirContext userCtx = (DirContext) result.getObject();

                // Change the BindUser
                ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userCtx.getNameInNamespace());
                ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, oldPassword);

                // Update password
                Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(oldPassword));
                Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(newPassword));
                ModificationItem olditem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, oldattr);
                ModificationItem newitem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, newattr);

                String dn = userCtx.getNameInNamespace();
                ctx.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[]{olditem, newitem});
            }
            ctx.close();
        } catch (final NamingException nE) {
            //
        } catch (Exception E) {
           //
        } finally {
          //
        }
    }
```

So, do you have any idea what needs to be changed? Or what the reason is that it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you just need to remove these lines:

```
// Change the BindUser
ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userCtx.getNameInNamespace());
ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, oldPassword);
```

You can't authenticate with the old password since it's no longer valid. But you also don't need to bind with the user's own credentials when changing the password, since you have to provide the old password in the request.

These lines may give you trouble too:

```
Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(oldPassword));
Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(newPassword));
```

The passwords do have to converted to unicode bytes, but they also have to be enclosed in double quotes too (`"`). So you'll probably have to add double quotes before passing it to `toUnicodeBytes()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can manage it in two steps:

In case "user must change password" it set, you should change the password of the user to an initial password as admin (bind).

```
                Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(oldPassword));
                Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(initialPassword));
```

Then, after a bind with the user with the (initial) password the user (himself) should change his password.

```
                Attribute oldattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(initialPassword)));
                Attribute newattr = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", toUnicodeBytes(newPassword));
```

(with double quotes, if you like)
This can work also in case if the user's password is expired.

Comment: You don't need to do it twice. You're just doing the same thing over again.